# Nonlinear isometric embedding of $ \mathbb{R} $ to $ (\mathbb{R}^2,\|.\|_\infty) $

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Prove that there is an isometric embedding of $ \mathbb{R} $ to $ (\mathbb{R}^2,\|.\|_\infty) $ that is not linear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a function $u:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which has slope $\le 1$ in all points. (E.g. let $u(x):=\sin(x)$ or  $u(x):=\left|(x\,{\rm mod}\,2)-1\right|$...)
and $\ f(x):=(x,\,u(x))$.

**Lemma.** For all $x,y$ we have $|u(x)-u(y)|\le |x-y|$.

So that, $\|f(x)-f(y)\|_\infty=\max(|x-y|,\,|u(x)-u(y)|)=|x-y|$.